# Facebook Permission not asked

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I created an app in facebook and added read_mailbox to the required permissions. 
When FB asks me to agree on granting access for the app, it only askes for my public profile and friendlist. 
All the other stuff works pretty well and I receive a auth_token as well.

I'm using the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely trying to set the permission in the app settings when you should be setting it in the scope while coding your application.

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_mailbox',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/